# How to set a specific items in spinner using customized pojo class list?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-activity

I am new to programming in Android and I am wondering how can I add an item drop-down list, I've tried but it's not exactly what I need.

For example I want to add 0 position  add "ALL" value in drop down list

I got like this

```
Song1
song2
```

but I want to get output like this

```
ALL
song1
song2
```

Here my source code

```
 //Here Song - Pojo class 
 //songlist - List Instance values retrieved from DB

    ContentSearchAdapterComposer adptercopmposer;
     artistList =new ArrayList<ArtistList>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contentsearch);

        initialization();

        daoSession = MApplication.getSessionWrite(ContentSearch.this);

        artist_ListDao =daoSession.getArtistListDao();          
        artistList =artist_ListDao.loadAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use "get(position).getTitle()" on "son_title" ?

Maybe youy should use:

```
holder.title.setText(son_title.getTitle());
```

right ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all in your getView method do changes like below

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    ViewHolder holder;      
    if (convertView == null) {

      convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);   
      holder = new ViewHolder();
      holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
      convertView.setTag(holder);  

    } else {
      holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }      


    Song son_title = mList.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(son_title.getTitle()); 

     return convertView;

    }
```

Secondly to show all as a very first element you should initialize your Song class(which you says as pojo) with "ALL" text while adding element in it then add the song id or data related to song in it.

Thirdly in your getCount method do following change

```
public int getCount() { 
return mList != null ? mList.size() : 0; 
}
```

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: how add a item in this ?

Comment: How did you add data in List<Song>songlist=new ArrayList<Song>(); ?

Comment: already added the drop down list its worked but my question add a item in spinner?

Comment: Post your code where you are adding data in list and then passing list into this spinner adapter

Comment: songlist =songDao.loadAll();

Comment: What this loadAll() method do. Please post your full source code of adding and getting data before adding into your question so that every one can see it

Comment: sry for that full source will post u tomorrow ? which time u will see ?

Comment: I will be available in morning 10am IST. Please make sure you post your full source code and related data to your question in your asked question area and not in comment of my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it like this in your constructor call.

```
public CustomListAdapter(Context context,List<Song> results) { 
mList = results;
Song ALL = new Song();
ALL.setTitle("ALL");
mList.add(0,ALL); 
mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); 
}
```

So, in your dropdown list the structure will be like this ALL, Song1,Song2...

Comment: Son means Song pojo class right 
 Son ALL = new Son();

Comment: sorry for the mistake, it is not Son. It is Song pojo class exactly. @kumar